# Gradle ModuleVersionNotFoundException for maven dependencies in local repository

Tags: maven, gradle

What can cause a org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException for maven dependencies installed (manually) in local repository?

In master build.gradle I have defined:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

and in one of submodules:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'fairPlayer.includes', name: 'lastfm-bindings', version: '160-SVN'
}
```

and I have

```
"lastfm-bindings-160-SVN.jar"
```

and

```
"lastfm-bindings-160-SVN.pom"
```

in

```
~\.m2\repository\fairPlayer\includes\lastfm-bindings\160-SVN\
```

I'm using 1.0-milestone7

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the dependency wasn't found. Do you have a `repositories` declaration for the subproject as well?

Comment: both groupId and dir should be named "fairplayer" instead of "fairPlayer". Gradle seems to dump groupId to lowercase and then search for artifact.